# MySQLi prepare statement good practice

Tags: php, security, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I want to see if my practice is good enough to protect from sql injection.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database);
$query = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? AND check = ?');
$query->bind_param('ii', $_GET['id'], $_POST['check']);
$query->execute();

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
...
}
```

I've seen that in some examples have this line before the while:

```
$result = $query->get_result();
```

And others that use trim(), intval() etc in $_GET/$_POST for safety.
Which is the best practice and safest way to avoid sql injections?

Comment: Side note: It should be `$_GET/$_POST` with the `_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *best* MySQLi prepared statement practice is apparently a **PDO prepared statement**

the code you posted above just makes no sense. To make it work, indeed you have to use get_result() function, which - alas! - [is not guaranteed to be available](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison#compatibility):

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? AND check = ?');
$query->bind_param('ii', $_GET['id'], $_POST['check']);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
...
}
```

while with PDO you need two times less code which is always guaranteed to work

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? AND check = ?');
$query->execute([$_GET['id'], $_POST['check']]);
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
...
}
```

not to mention other PDO's wonderful features

> And others that use trim(), intval() etc

these things are just irrelevant it SQL, you may use them for whatever else reason.